# Best way to ensure that an operation is not performed on the same value in a dictionary twice?

Tags: python

Currently I am doing it like this..

```
def operation(x):
    return x

items_seen = []
d = {"a":10, "b": 5,"c": 6,"d": 7, "e": 7}

for x in d.values():

    if x not in items_seen:
        print operation(x)
        items_seen.append(x)
```

But I was wondering if there was a better way.. ?

Comment: What you try to achieve with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to apply the `operation` function to the unique values of a dictionary, you can iterate over the `set` of its values:

```
def operation(x):
    return x

d = {"a": 10, "b": 5, "c": 6, "d": 7, "e": 7}

for x in set(d.values()):
    print operation(x)
```

**Output**

```
10
5
6
7
```

Aside: I've changed your dictionary name from `aList` to `d` for clarity.

Comment: Yeah, that's better. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, what if it was like this. d = {"a":[10, 0], "b": [5,0],"c":[6,0],"d": [7,0], "e": [7,0]} and I wanted to perform the operation on x[0] ?

Comment: You could change to `for x in set(map(tuple, d.values())):
    print operation(x[0])`. To explain properly it might require a different question...

Comment: Basically lists aren't hashable, so you have to convert the `values` list of lists to a list of tuples

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your values `list` to a `set` first to ensure that every value only occurs once:

```
for x in set(aList.values()):
    print operation(x)
```